# How to draw a figure 8 knot with arrows and labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

It is my first time to try to draw knot in TeX, and I find a a tutorial for drawing knot：
https://loopspace.mathforge.org/HowDidIDoThat/TeX/NewKnots/
But I encountered some difficities in trying to understand it.

1. How does "controls" work in the following code?

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \path[spath/save=trefoil]
   (0,2) .. controls +(2.2,0) and +(120:-2.2) ..
   (210:2) .. controls +(120:2.2) and +(60:2.2) ..
   (-30:2) .. controls +(60:-2.2) and +(-2.2,0) .. (0,2);
   \tikzset{
   every trefoil component/.style={draw},
   trefoil component 1/.style={blue},
   trefoil component 2/.style={green, dashed, |<->|},
   trefoil component 3/.style={magenta, line width=2pt},
   spath/knot={trefoil}{15pt}{1,3,5},
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

I understand that
(0, 2) (210: 2) (-30: 2)
are three points in the plane. But what does, for example, controls +(2.2, 0) mean? I tried to draw help lines and I find that +(2.2, 0) does not mean the point (2.2, 0). It makes me confused.

2. Can I modifiy the following codes to get a figure 8 knot with orientation and labels?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
    \path[spath/save=figure8]
    ([closed]0,0) .. (1.5,1) .. (.5,2) ..
    (-.5,1) .. (.5,0) .. (0,-.5) .. (-.5,0) ..
    (.5,1) .. (-.5,2) .. (-1.5,1) .. (0,0);
    \tikzset{
    every spath component/.style={draw},
    spath/knot={figure8}{15pt}{1,3,...,7}
    }
    \path (0,-.7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

In this document, the author give a example code of figure 8 knot. But I what to add arrows and labels. It seems I can achieve it to modify the example of trefoil. I thinke If I can really understand how "contros" works in the example of trefoil, combining the coordinates in the example of figure 8, maybe I can draw what I want.

Here is another question related to mine:[How do I draw the orientation of a knot in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473077/how-do-i-draw-the-orientation-of-a-knot-in-tikz) But somehow, my computer can't compile the code in it.

The following picture is what I am trying to draw.

[image]

Comment: The syntax `+(...)` defines _relative_ coordinates, you can find out about them in the TikZ manual.  For the second part, it would seem that you are trying to add labels and decorations to a path, which doesn't involve changing the actual path, so you don't need to mess around with the construction.  Could you add an image of what you're after?  Hand drawn is fine.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for help, but I still can't understand "(0,2).. controls +(2.2, 0)". If + means relative coordinates, why there is no point (2.2, 2) on the figure?  I edit my question and post the picture I want to draw.

Comment: The `controls` part is to do with how tikz constructs paths and is covered in the manual.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you for your advice. After reading the help document, I find a way to draw it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking the paths with arrows and labels can be done by adding a decoration to the `every spath component` style.  And by using `spath component` instead of `every spath component`, we get the label number passed as the `#1` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638097/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  hobby,
  intersections,
  spath3,
  decorations.markings,
  arrows.meta,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\path[spath/save=figure8]
([closed]0,0) .. (1.5,1) .. (.5,2) ..
(-.5,1) .. (.5,0) .. (0,-.5) .. (-.5,0) ..
(.5,1) .. (-.5,2) .. (-1.5,1) .. (0,0);
\tikzset{
  spath component/.style={
    draw,
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Latex}},
      mark=at position 0.5 with {
        \path (0,0) +(0,1ex) node {\(#1\)};
      },
    }
  },
  spath/knot={figure8}{15pt}{1,3,...,7}
}
\path (0,-.7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: labelled figure 8 knot]